# Multiple render error in rails app while generating pdf file via wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf, wicked-gem

I'm using wicked PDF in my rails app to generate PDF. and that is done by a private function generate_pdf in my controler becase after the purchase process i want to generate that pdf and then mailer function to send that pdf to user.

error

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

code is something lie this.

```
 def place_order
... some code

    download_new_pdf(@pur)
    UserMailer.confirm_order(@pur).deliver

   format.html { redirect_to(:action=>'order_confirmed/'+@pur[:id].to_s) } 
end
```

and the helper function will be

```
def download_new_pdf(id)

@my_ticket = Purchase.find(id)
@event = Event.find(@my_ticket[:event_id])
render :pdf => "#{@my_ticket[:random_no]}.pdf",
 :template => 'tickets/download_invoice.html.erb',
 :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public/data/docs', "#{@my_ticket[:random_no]}.pdf")   
end
```

place_order will do all the DB stuff and at the end generate pdf, send mail and redirect to conformation page. But here it's giving me multiple render error coz of

```
   format.html { redirect_to(:action=>'order_confirmed/'+@pur[:id].to_s) }
```

and

```
  render :pdf => "#{@my_ticket[:random_no]}.pdf",
     :template => 'tickets/download_invoice.html.erb',
     :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public/data/docs', "#{@my_ticket[:random_no]}.pdf")
```

i tried putting and return but still no luck,Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is simple. You are render in `download_new_pdf` and redirecting in `place_order`at the same time.  It looks like you need to create the pdf file and store in the file system, not to show it immediately to the user, so, check the [readme](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#super-advanced-usage), here is explained how to just create the PDF and don't render it to the client